# Spring security configuration loses context

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I am migrating my deprecated spring security code and I am facing a problem : after the user's authentication (and he is authenticated), the spring contextHolder seems to be lost and the authentication vanishes. Therefore my connection does not work and the first api call redirects again to the login page

I followed this documentation to migrate from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to the new spring security way : https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

I removed all complex code to start fresh from base username/password authentication. This is the whole SecurityConfiguration file I have. I still have the same problem :

```html
package com.ecervo.cervoprint.config.security;

import com.ecervo.cervoprint.config.ApiPathProperties;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.repository.users.AuthorityProfileRepository;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.repository.users.GroupRepository;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.repository.users.UserGroupRepository;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.repository.users.UserRepository;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.CervoprintAccessDeniedHandler;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.security.saml.config.SamlSettings;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.service.parameter.ParameterService;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.service.projection.DozerBeanConverter;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.service.users.UserDetailsInitializer;
import com.ecervo.cervoprint.support.CurrentTimeService;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApiPathProperties.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private static final String HTTP_AUTHENTICATION = "/api/authentication";

    @Nonnull
    private final ApiPathProperties apiPathProperties;

    @Nonnull
    private final AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Nonnull
    private final Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Nonnull
    private final AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Nonnull
    private final AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "OptionalUsedAsFieldOrParameterType", "squid:S00107" })
    public SecurityConfiguration(
        @Nonnull ApiPathProperties apiPathProperties,
        @Nonnull AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler,
        @Nonnull AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler,
        @Nonnull Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint,
        @Nonnull AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler,
    ) {
        this.apiPathProperties = apiPathProperties;
        this.ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler = ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;
        this.authenticationEntryPoint = authenticationEntryPoint;
        this.ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler = ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler = ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
    ) {
        // Ensure that DaoAuthenticationProvider is always registered as it is the fallback.
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);

        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
        providerManager.setEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication(false);
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public class HttpSecurityConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
            return web ->
                web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
                    .antMatchers("/assets/**")
                    .antMatchers(apiPathProperties.getApiDocs() + "/**")
                    .antMatchers("/test/**")
                    .antMatchers("/jms/**")
                    .antMatchers("/api/print-queue/**")
                    .antMatchers("/api/update/**");
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl(HTTP_AUTHENTICATION)
                .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "CSRF-TOKEN")
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated();
            return http.build();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class UserDetailsServiceConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public UserDetailsInitializer userDetailsInitializer(
            UserRepository userRepository,
            GroupRepository groupRepository,
            UserGroupRepository userGroupRepository,
            AuthorityProfileRepository authorityProfileRepository,
            DozerBeanConverter dozerBeanConverter,
            ParameterService parameterService,
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder
        ) {
            return new UserDetailsInitializer(
                userRepository,
                groupRepository,
                userGroupRepository,
                authorityProfileRepository,
                dozerBeanConverter,
                passwordEncoder,
                parameterService
            );
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    static class PasswordEncoderConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

The logs are too large to post here, so I posted it here : https://paste.quest/?edc9a0a38d46aa6a#2g9chU2JzsGPw58BaZdjs56rSYFvW2WHBUqqSXJiyR1U

UPDATE :

Ok so I finally stumbled on the code which breaks everything :

```
    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() {
        MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(SecurityContextHolder.class);
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("setStrategyName");
        methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
        return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
    }
```

If I comment out this, I can connect. This was added for Async methods as explained here : https://dev.to/spooz/spring-security-and-threads

I suppose the migration broke this. Now I have to find a solution to migrate this, I suppose @Async methods won't work without something like this.

Comment: im guessing your problem is that you probably built your spring application based on some poorly written blog posts in a non recommended way and when you upgraded the blog wont help you since your initial implementation was faulty. You have posted extremely little code, so all i can do is to guess, since i have nothing to go on here. You have a custom login endpoint and you are handing out a JWT straight to the browsers which is dangerous and not recommended by the spring team or any major security resource. And then you have a custom home written JWTfilter..

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for your answer. I didn't want to overflow with code that might not be useful. I hear what you said about the JWT filter. I edited my original post in order to remove a lot of code to start fresh and keep only what is needed for a username/password authentication. I added the whole code I have in my SecurityConfiguration file. I hope this will help to investigate what is happening.

Comment: This is not a ”minimal reproducible example” you have a lot of questionable code, for instance why are you building your own second ProviderManager when spring already has one provided for you when using FormLogin, and what has the rate limiting filter to do with the problem? And lots of disabling of headers and features. Pleace __reduce__ your code to the bare minimum. Also your logs seem to be cut off. We need FULL logs including full stacktraces

Comment: I reduced the code further. As you can see, I'm no expert at all in spring security, that's why I need help. I have a custom ProviderManager because there are multiple UserDetailsService for different login options (which I disabled) like saml, ldap etc. I don't think this is related. The definition of the custom ProviderManager comes from the spring security documentation. I posted the whole logs also. Be aware that the first api call to account should be ignored, it happens when I click on the page automaticaly, before the login process is actually launched.

Comment: I updated the original post, I found the code which breaks the authentication

Comment: The blog you linked to is 6 years old, and that piece of code wasnt even included in your question. If you want concurrent capabilities this is what you should be reading https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/concurrency.html#_spring_security_concurrency_classes this points out how important it is with minimal reproducible examples in questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documentation ! I The code of my app is like 5M lines, there is stuff everywhere, I myself didn't know that this code existed so that's why I didn't put it in my original question.